# Why Content Delivery in Sitecore 9.3 is treating users as editors?

Tags: authentication, content-delivery

After upgrading to `Sitecore 9.3`, some times, users are not able to log in to **Content Delivery** (using ADFS) because we're exceeding the maximum editor's restriction by license. It's weird because is **Content Delivery**. The error I'm seeing in logs is:

```
The maximum number of simultaneously active (logged-in) editors exceeded. The User extranet\xxxx cannot be logged in to the system. The maximum of editors allowed by license is 10.
```

The user is then redirected to `/sitecore/client/Applications/LicenseOptions/StartPage` but is throwing 404 error, obviously, because it is Content Delivery site.

Comment: what domain are your users created under?

Comment: @RichardSeal the users are created under extranet. Actually the error in logs says: The User extranet\xxxx cannot be logged in to the system.

Comment: what Sitecore Site are the users being authenticated against?

Comment: @MarkCassidy We're using external ADFS login, so the users are redirected to login first with ADFS and then redirected to "/sitecore/client/Applications/LicenseOptions/StartPage" (the usual pre-Kick user page). Ideally should be redirected to redirectUrl.

Comment: Read my question. When hooking up federated authenticated, you tie this to a site. Which site are you using?

Comment: @MarkCassidy you mean this? <sites hint="list">
                        <site>shell</site>
                        <site>website</site>
                    </sites>

Comment: Any luck finding the fix? We have the same issue on Sitecore 9.3 :( [Please treat it as a comment as i don't have enough reputation to add one]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the support help I got and fixed it:
Could you please try overriding the CheckDomainGuard processor using the following:

```
namespace CustomNamespace
{
    public class CustomCheckDomainGuard : Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.CheckDomainGuard
    {
        public CustomCheckDomainGuard(BaseLog log) : base(log)
        {

        }

        public override void Process(SignedInArgs args)
        {
            if (string.Equals(args.Site.Name, Sitecore.Constants.ShellSiteName, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                base.Process(args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then please use a patch file containing the following to patch it in:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
                <processor type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.CheckDomainGuard, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" patch:instead="*[@type='CustomNamespace.CustomCheckDomainGuard, CustomAssembly']" resolve="true" />
            </owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This worked for us also! +1. However, just note that you have the patch the other way around it should be: 

<processor type="CustomNamespace.CustomCheckDomainGuard, CustomAssembly" patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.CheckDomainGuard, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']" resolve="true" />

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore support has registered this a bug with reference number 366550, and there is a hotfix available for 9.2 and 9.3 [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/646268).